# AWS Cloudformation stack level tags being removed

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, stack, aws-cloudformation

I created a stack with this:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name dummy-stack \
 --template-body file://template.yaml \
 --capabilities CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND \
 --tags Key=tag1key,Value=tag1value \
        Key=tag2key,Value=tag2value \
        Key=tag3key,Value=tag3value
```

With a very simple definition:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform:
  - AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  SNSTopic:
    Type: "AWS::SNS::Topic"
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Properties:
      TopicName: "dummy-topic-delete"
```

After doing that, my `Topic` has tags as expected, but there are none in the generated `template`.
However, when I update the stack using `sam deploy...` the tags on the `Topic` disappear.
I would like to be able to add some global tags that will get added to my resources so I don't have the same items repeated over and over.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation stack level tags are propagated down to the deployed resources.
But it is not a "transformation" of a template itself - so you wouldn't see them in generated body of a template.